# Visual Studio 2019 WebBrowser Extension Problem

Tags: visual-studio

I'm Using Visual Studio 2019 and I have a Windows Forms Project, But In This Project I can't Find WebbBrowser Extension, Can Anyone Help Me?

Answer (score 0):

Having this same issue, IDK why your post was -1 other than the fact Google held the answer.
[Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/864939/webbrowser-control-no-longer-supported.html) is a link to the Dev Community page I found. Apparently, the web browser has been removed in the 2019 version. Looks like I'll be using 2017 for some projects.

Another user also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426107/why-doesnt-webbrowser-work-in-visual-studio-2019). and got a better answer than mine.

That's like making a new car and thinking only of left-handed people...